# div will not change size with CSS properties

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome

I am trying to add a surrounding div to an icon in React using plain CSS, but for some reason the div will not respond to size.

On hover, the background color changes but I cannot increase the size of the div with CSS for some reason -  it just stays the same dimensions as the icon it's wrapping.

Here's my JSX:

```js
        <div
          onClick={handleShowLegend}
          onKeyDown={handleShowLegend}
          role="button"
          tabIndex={0}
          className="showLegendButton"
        >
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            icon={showLegend ? faChevronUp : faChevronDown}
            size="2x"
          />
        </div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```css
.showLegendButton {
    width: 100px; // this does not work
    height: 100px; // this does not work
    padding-right: 28px;
    :hover {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

#### Update

Here's what implementing the first answer looks like on hover. I want to only see a background color bigger than the icon on hover, not all the time.

[image]

```
.showLegendButton {
    padding: 50px;
    background-color: #ff7979;
    :hover {
        background-color: #e0e0e0;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add !important with height and width just something like here:                    
    width: 100px !important;
    height: 100px !important;

Comment: This issue doesn't require important. Besides good design in most cases can do without important.

Comment: Thank you, `!important` didn't work

Comment: you need to give direct padding not width and height...

Comment: Is that SASS? You need to tag it as such because it's invalid CSS.

Comment: Hmm, how so? I got it from here: https://www.edwardbeazer.com/how-to-add-hover-events-to-any-react-component/

Comment: You cannot nest properties in CSS. If it's not SASS then it must be a React thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use padding to get that surround effect instead of width and height

```
.showLegendButton {
    padding: 20px; // this
    // padding-right: 28px; and use margin right in here instead of padding
    background-color: #colorhere  ; // what color do you like
    :hover {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this did not make the size of the background color any bigger.

Comment: you need to add background-color on its parent too. check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question after implementing your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You're not declaring in your css that you want to change the size properties on hover, only the color and cursor. Move your height and width declarations into the pseudo-selector like this.

```
.showLegendButton {
    padding-right: 28px;
    :hover {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100px; 
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

and it should give you the result you're looking for, (if I understand correctly from your question that you want the coloured background to increase in size on hover).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add !important with height and width just something like below:
OR you need to give direct padding not fixed height and width:
Thanks

```css
.showLegendButton {
        width: 100px !important;
        height: 100px !important;
        padding-right: 28px;
        :hover {
            background-color: #ff0000;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
    //or
   .showLegendButton {
        padding: 28px;
        :hover {
            background-color: #ff0000;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
```